# Decorator Design Pattern with JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

to start I want to say I have basic experience with Hibernate and Spring boot, but for a project I have, I decided to use them in order to learn them better.

The current problem I have is, I don't know how to represent the Decorator design pattern in my app with JPA/hibernate to be able to save them in the same table... I'll leave the code down below.

The idea is to have a Bus with certain information, but it can have a route and a driver, but they must be assigned with the decorator design pattern.

Thanks in advance for answering!

**IBus.java**

```
package com.softeng.finalsofteng.model.decorator;

public interface IBus {

    String getTodo();

    void setTodo(String placa, int capacidad, String marca);
}
```

**Bus.java**

```
package com.softeng.finalsofteng.model.decorator;

public class Bus implements IBus {

    private String placa;
    private int capacidad;
    private String marca;

    public Bus(String placa, int capacidad, String marca) {
        this.placa = placa;
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String placa) {
        this.placa = placa;
    }

    public int getCapacidad() {
        return capacidad;
    }

    public void setCapacidad(int capacidad) {
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTodo() {
        return "Placa: " + placa + ",Capacidad: " + capacidad + ",Marca: " + marca;
    }

    @Override
    public void setTodo(String placa, int capacidad, String marca) {
        this.placa = placa;
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
        this.marca = marca;
    }
}
```

**BusInfo.java**

```
package com.softeng.finalsofteng.model.decorator;

abstract class BusInfo implements IBus {

    protected IBus busInfo;

    public BusInfo(IBus busInfo) {
        this.busInfo = busInfo;
    }


    @Override
    public String getTodo() {
        return busInfo.getTodo();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTodo(String placa, int capacidad, String marca) {
        busInfo.setTodo(placa, capacidad, marca);
    }
}
```

**BusConductor.java**

```
package com.softeng.finalsofteng.model.decorator;

public class BusConductor extends BusInfo {

    private String conductor;
    private String[] parametros;

    public BusConductor(IBus busInfo, String conductor) {
        super(busInfo);
        this.conductor = conductor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTodo() {
        return busInfo.getTodo() + addConductor(this.conductor);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTodo(String placa, int capacidad, String marca) {
        busInfo.setTodo(placa, capacidad, marca);
    }

    public String addConductor(String conductor){
        return ",Conductor: " + conductor;
    }
}
```

**BusRuta.java**

```
package com.softeng.finalsofteng.model.decorator;

public class BusRuta extends BusInfo {

    private String ruta;

    public BusRuta(IBus busInfo, String ruta) {
        super(busInfo);
        this.ruta = ruta;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTodo() {
        return busInfo.getTodo() + addRuta(this.ruta);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTodo(String placa, int capacidad, String marca) {
        busInfo.setTodo(placa, capacidad, marca);
    }

    public String addRuta(String ruta){
        return ",Ruta: " + ruta;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you show has no relation to JPA/HIbernate. Please explain how is it related to JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: I want to store the buses in a single table, that will have all the info including the driver and route, but the driver and route have to be implemented with JPA

Comment: While it is certainly possible to store different classes in a single table, such decision shouldn't be taken without some though on pros and cons. You could start with a tutorial like [Hibernate Inheritance Mapping](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance) before diving deeply.

Comment: With JPA it can be very hard to implement, because in JPA a logical relation between objects should be implemented via *relation*. Why do you want to use such a complex structure? Why not very simple structure with relation?

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying, in the end I decided to not use the decorator at all, but to have a class Bus where stuff can be null.